# ¿Como detener la ejecucion de un hilo que esta en espera, despues de un tiempo determinado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

El problema que tengo, es que no puedo detener la ejecucion de un hilo, y me sale el siguiente error:

```
raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

Descripción de Funcionamiento:

En la clase `Inicial`, tengo un `QPushButton` el cual inicia la función `def Uno()` la cual procede a hcer 2 cosas:

1.- Inicia la animacion de un .gif dentro de una `QLabel`

2.- Inicia la clase `Hilo` que ejecuta el nuevo hilo.

*La clase Hilo()*

La clase recibe como argunmento una función la cual es la función `def Dos()`, esta funcion valida el resultado de la función `Conexion()`.

```
def Dos(self):
        if Conexion() == "ok":
            self.alerta.emit(0)
        else:
            self.alerta.emit(1)
```

**Conexion()**

La funcion conexión es una funcion que funciona con sokckets ye espera la conexion de un usuario en un lapso de 5 segundos y de no haber conexion lanza una exepción tipo `Timeout`:

```
import socket

def Conexion():
    try:
        servidor = socket.socket()
        _nombre = socket.gethostname()
        _ip = socket.gethostbyname(_nombre)
        conec = (_ip,5555)

        servidor.bind(conec)
        servidor.listen(1)
        servidor.settimeout(5)

        cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

        Respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()

        if Respuesta == "ok":
            cliente.sendall("conectado".encode())
            return "conectado"
    except socket.timeout as e:
        return "error"
```

Al lanzar la exepción `timeout`, en la clase `Ìnicial()` se emite una señal para poder lanzar un `QMessageBox` de error y aqui se debe de detener la ejecución de la función y Hilo que se ejecuto.

**Problema en Función**

En función el proceso es el sigueinte: Presiona el boton, este boton inicia el hilo y la animación en el QLabel, el hilo ejecuta la función `def Dos()` que evalua el resultado de la función `Conexion()` si la función devuelve `error` entonces se lanza el `QMessageBox` de error.

Pero si se vuelve a presional el boton aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel-Dell\Desktop\Principal.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    self.Boton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Uno())
  File "C:\Users\Angel-Dell\Desktop\Principal.py", line 40, in Uno
    self._Hilo.start()
  File "C:\Users\Angel-Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading
.py", line 842, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Process returned 3221226505 (0xc0000409)        execution time : 14.479 s
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado esperado**

El resultado esperado es que el hilo se detenga al mismo tiempo que la exepción `timeout` termine, o bien generar la excepción dentro de el `Hilo`

poe jemplo algo asi en la funcion `run()` de la Clase `Hilo()`:

`def run(self):
   try:
      self.funcion()
   except : # <- Aqui exepción de tiempo por ejemplo despues de 5 segundos lanzar excepcion`

**Principal.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QPushButton,QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from Servidor import Conexion
import threading

class Hilo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,objeto,funcion):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.obj = object
        self.fun = funcion

    def run(self):
        self.fun()

class Inicial(QMainWindow):
    alerta = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.Boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.Boton.setText("Presiona")
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Uno())

        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.move(100,30)
        self.Label.setStyleSheet("Background:lightgrey;")
        self.Label.resize(200,200)

        self._Hilo = Hilo(self,self.Dos)

        self.alerta.connect(self.Finalizado)

    def Uno(self):
        _movie = QtGui.QMovie("Animacion.gif")
        self.Label.setMovie(_movie)
        self.Label.setScaledContents(True)
        _movie.start()

        self._Hilo.start()
    def Dos(self):
        if Conexion() == "ok":
            self.alerta.emit(0)
        else:
            self.alerta.emit(1)

    def Finalizado(self,alert):
        if alert == 0:
            self.Label.setText("Todo ok")
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(None,"Error de Conexion con Servidor","Tiempo de ejecucion agotado")
            #Aui deberia de detenerse el hilo




app = QApplication([])
i = Inicial()
i.show()
i.resize(600,400)
app.exec_()
```

**Servidor.py**

```
import socket

def Conexion():
    try:
        servidor = socket.socket()
        _nombre = socket.gethostname()
        _ip = socket.gethostbyname(_nombre)
        conec = (_ip,5555)

        servidor.bind(conec)
        servidor.listen(1)
        servidor.settimeout(5)

        cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

        Respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()

        if Respuesta == "ok":
            cliente.sendall("conectado".encode())
            return "conectado"
    except socket.timeout as e:
        return "error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te da es porque el thread solo puede ser iniciado una sola vez, es decir que debes iniciar un nuevo thread, en ese caso usa esto:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

de esta forma siempre se crea un nuevo hilo. por lo que comentas de como detenerlo, el manual dice que si no hay un loop en el hilo este morira despues de ejecutar la ultima linea, y no veo ningun loop asi que el supongo que muere solo.

Comment: Pero mi clase Hilo(), es un thread, si se supone que el hilo muere automaticamente al lanzarse la `timeout` exception, no se supone que deberia poder volver a ejecutarlo sin problema de nuevo

Comment: el error que te da creo que es claro =>  raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once") => "los hilos solo se pueden iniciar una vez"